# How can i use custom label values in Squery- of apex class

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

Can anyone help me to form the dynamic query with the LIMIT value stored in custom label.

```
Public String valueForLimit  = System.Label.BuyListCustomlabelLimit;
```

How can i use the valueForLimit in Squery as LIMIT

sQuery = 'Select id from  ABDS LIMIT valueForLimit';

```
error :- First error: expecting a colon, found 'valueForLimit'
```

Comment: Have you stored number value in custom label?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error while concatenating the String. It should be as below.

```
Public String valueForLimit  = System.Label.BuyListCustomlabelLimit;
..........
..........
sQuery = 'Select id from ABDS LIMIT ' + valueForLimit;
```